# CMD /C and echo on a remote machine invoking command

Tags: c#, cmd

i got a mysterious phenomena if i am going to write a file to the share folder on a remote machine.

```
object[] theProcessToRun2 = { "CMD.EXE /C " + '"' + "echo.exe test 123 4 5 6 7" + '"' + " " + "> " + '"' + @"C:\temp10\Pythontest.py" + '"' };

using (var managementClass = new ManagementClass(serviceScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions()))
{
managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun2);
}
```

If i write the same code on the cmd line on the remote machine, it writes a file.

ServiceScope and so on is correct ( i tried it with a python script on the remote machine and works fine... so here is not the error).

What did i do wrong, or did not see it correctly ?

Comment: What is the error?  No file, or an exception?

Comment: I got no exception. It writes no file

Comment: That mysterious phenomena might be called "Permissions"

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need `CMD.EXE` and `/C` to be separate arguments from the rest.  So your array should be made up of at least 3 strings and no need for the double quotes.  I'm not completely sure about how you need to separate the redirect.

Comment: I would guess that if there isn't any exception, then it's not a permission thing.  Why not change the `theProcessToRun2` to `Notepad.exe` and see if it starts up.  It might just be your `CMD.EXE` isn't correct.

Comment: Try to use the full path to `cmd.exe` (that is the path that is stored in environment variable `%ComSpec%`)...

Comment: Ok, i make some little steps now. Its writing a file if i am adding a /S to the CMD.EXE. Now it writes the File, but it did not write the content of the Echo arguments

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the string you build for CMD command line. Let' see

```
{ "CMD.EXE /C " + '"' + "echo.exe test 123 4 5 6 7" + '"' + " " + "> " + '"' + @"C:\temp10\Pythontest.py" + '"' }
```

This would be the actual string:

`CMD.EXE /c "echo.exe test 123 4 5 6 7" > "C:\temp10\Pythontest.py"`

CMD has its own rules for processing command line arguments. This is the description from CMD help which can bee seen by typing `CMD /?` at command prompt

> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
>   the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
>   used to process quote (") characters:
>
> 1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>         on the command line are preserved:
>
>    - no /S switch
>    - exactly two quote characters
>    - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>         where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>         two quote characters
>    - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>         of an executable file.
> 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>         a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>         remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>         any text after the last quote character.

Clearly your string is not covered by the case 1 so case 2 will applied to your command line string. That means CMD will remove the first and last quote after `/C` switch before executing it. So CMD will try to execute this:

`echo.exe test 123 4 5 6 7" > "C:\temp10\Pythontest.py`

Now you see that the redirection operator is between quotes, It is now just a literal `>` surrounded in quotes so no redirection is performed and this will be printed on console:

> exe test 123 4 5 6 7" > "C:\temp10\Pythontest.py

Note that `echo` is an internal command for CMD and windows does have any executable named `echo.exe`. By using `echo.exe` you are actually using internal `echo` command which `.exe` is it's argument. `echo` always skips the first character so `.` is eliminated and `exe` will printed.

So this would be the correct string which work as intended:

`CMD.EXE /c echo test 123 4 5 6 7 > "C:\temp10\Pythontest.py"`

Thus

```
object[] theProcessToRun2 = { "CMD.EXE /C " + "echo test 123 4 5 6 7" + " > " + '"' + @"C:\temp10\Pythontest.py" + '"' };
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got some enlightenment from a German forum.

The reason, why echo is not working in that case is:

echo tried to output it values to the stdout - which should be linked to a UI element. After the call is on a remote machine, there is no UI element who can be reached. So all the output is going into the Nirvana.

That's the reason, why it writes a file, but without content.